# creating link with knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

i have an observable array in my viewmodel "IdOfInvitedSocialCompaigns" , this property contain  array of id  , and i want to create link like this :

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Compaign","Confirmation", new {socialbuzzCompaignId = id})
```

how can i built link like this with knockoutjs, here is a part of viewmodel :

```
  function DashboardViewModel() {
    var self = this;        
    self.IdOfInvitedSocialCompaigns = ko.observableArray([]);
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to build the partially Razor generated URL directly into your binding  markup if you get the escaping right, but it'd be messy. I'd probably define a base URL property on DashboardViewModel which gets populated by the page on DOM ready like so:

```
dashVM.urls.confirmCampaignUrl = '@(Url.Action("Campaign", "Confirmation"))';
```

and then have a function which gets a specific URL:

```
self.getCampaignConfirmationUrl = function(id) {
    return self.urls.confirmCampaignUrl + '/' + id;
};
```

bound like so:

```
<!-- ko foreach: IdOfInvitedSocialCompaigns  -->
<a data-bind="attr: { href: dashVM.getCampaignConfirmationUrl($data) }">Confirm</a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Mr Tom, note that the url will be like this : Compaign/Confirmation?socialbuzzCompaignId=id

Comment: OK, well you could either hardcode the socialbuzzCompaignId parameter name into that base URL property, or you could set it as something like: @(Url.Action("Compaign","Confirmation", new {socialbuzzCompaignId = "{0}"})) and then the function would be: return self.urls.confirmCampaignUrl.replace('{0}', id)

Comment: Actually Url.Action will encode those curly brackets, which you'd have to deal with, but you get the idea.